# Connect 2 (or more) Open vSwitch bridge on separate servers

Tags: openflow, openvswitch

I have some server with OVS bridge on each. Each server has several VMs inside, all connected to the OVS bridge.

All bridges connect to the FloodLight OpenFlow controller and VMs inside 1 host can reach other. This is example of 2 host, A and B. VMs inside HOST A may get different or same subnet with VMs inside HOST B:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|   +------+      +------+   |-----+
|   | VM-1 |      | VM-2 |   | brA |
|   +------+      +------+   |-----+------>--------+
+++++++++++ HOST A +++++++++++                    \|/
                                            +---------------+
                                            | OF controller |
                                            +---------------+
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                    /|\
|   +------+      +------+   |-----+------>--------+
|   | VM-3 |      | VM-4 |   | brB |
|   +------+      +------+   |-----+
+++++++++++ HOST B +++++++++++
```

**Success:** VM-1 reach VM-2.

**How to: VM-1 reach VM-3???**

Update: before connect to OF controller, VMs can reach the internet with POSTROUTING masquerade rule but failed after connected to OF controller.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: What functionalities OF Controller support? Dump flows of the bridges to see if any rules have been installed by the controller

Comment: After days and nights, I think I found the problem. It's described at https://groups.google.com/a/openflowhub.org/forum/#!msg/floodlight-dev/rH5oocDztWs/wHt_3elrBwAJ.
I will try to downgrade the version to 2.4.1 and will inform soon. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open vSwitch 2.5 and above can not work with the latest FloodLight controller. Version 2.4.1 should work ok.